# How to force Graphiz tool (dot, neato,...) to accept some initial node placement

Tags: graphviz, dot, neato

Is there a way to force any Graphviz tool (dot, neato,...) to accept some initial node placement and keep them in this position, while placing the remaining nodes using its standard algorithm ?

I have tried to play with the "pos" node attribute in Neato, without success.

Comment: +1 because I've tried exactly the same thing and got to the same conclusion ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use

```
pos="x,y!"
```

The exclamation mark is important to do what you want !

Comment: Thanks Greg ! That's the answer.
I now see it in NEATO User’s Manual, April 26, 2004, page 9.